# Render SVG and PNG/JPG with the same Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

Currently, I am using `Image.network` to render PNG/JPG and `SvgPicture.network` to render SVG.

However, is there a Widget that is able to detect the actual image type and automatically selects either `Image.network` or `SvgPicture.network` depending on the type?

Comment: write a custom `StatelessWidget` and implement `build` method depending the image type

Comment: I was hoping someone else solved it already. I guess the approach is to do a HEAD call to the URL, probe the type, then switch.

Comment: your resources do not have file extensions? if its the case, then yes, you would need a HEAD request and use `FutureBuilder`

Comment: or use `NetworkImage` specialized `ImageProvider` and judge based on `headers` property

Comment: Maybe try to make your resource have some file extensions